# Loading Google GWT app dynamically into a legacy webpage

Tags: gwt

I have a legacy page which works already with ajax and I would like to load an GWT app (2.0.4) into that app without reloading the whole page. Our framework normally can insert css and js files into the page by evaluation "eval(...)" the js code or url which is sent in an html fragment. But the gwt bootstrap js code fails while evaluating and produces an blank page with a js error that the "app-name" object is not defined.

Does anybody has an idea why the gwt bootstrap file behaves like that?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/27935f30327220cf/aeef0989fc67b415?lnk=gst&q=iframe+module#aeef0989fc67b415) why inserting a `<script>` tag pointing to your `nocache.js` is not working.

Check [this](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/22233e52dc52af48/54a1388ad949241c?lnk=gst&q=iframe+module#54a1388ad949241c) out for a possible solution.

[gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) might also be interesting for you.

Couldn't you include the `no.cache.js` file in the header of the pages you wanna extend with GWT and replace existing elements with the widgets you need (as mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage))?

Comment: Thanks for the answer above. The problem seem to be that the gwt *.nocache.js file has some document.write code inside which replaces the whole body and this results in an blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but the GWT bootstrapping process typically begins with a `<script>` tag on the page pointing to your generated `nocache.js` file.  This script runs to check the capabilities, etc., of your browser, which it uses to request the cache.html file corresponding to your browser.

If you want to load this dynamically (i.e., not immediately on page load), why not try adding the script tag dynamically by adding a script element with the href attribute set to your nocache.js, at which point it will begin the bootstrapping process as normal. No need to call `eval()` on anything, GWT does that itself.

Comment: I just tried it with an dynamic <script> tag but this does not help. It loads the file and the screen gets blank and the page keeps loading. Did you try to load an app dynamic yourself?